# Create new object out of huge array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I retrieve a huge array from the server (contains 2000+ objects). the structure of this array is like this:

```
const arr = [
{code: 'A', text:'blabla', codeParent:'-'},
{code: 'B', text:'blabla', codeParent:'-'},
{code: 'C', text:'blabla', codeParent:'-'},
{code: 'D', text:'blabla', codeParent:'-'},
{code: '01', text:'blabla', codeParent:'B'},
{code: '02', text:'blabla', codeParent:'C'},
{code: '03', text:'blabla', codeParent:'D'},
{code: '04', text:'blabla', codeParent:'A'},
{code: '05', text:'blabla', codeParent:'A'},
{code: '06', text:'blabla', codeParent:'B'},
...
]
```

The object that I want to make looks like this:

```
const obj = {
A: [array of all object with codeParent 'A'],
B: [array of all object with codeParent 'B'],
C: [array of all object with codeParent 'C'],
D: [array of all object with codeParent 'D']
}
```

Does anyone know the best way to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a couple things about your output that weren't entirely clear from your explanation, but appear to be the case from your sample output:

1. The output is collated by the `codeParent` property
2. You are skipping items that have `codeParent: '-'`

Then, you can just iterate through the big array and populate the output object as you go:

```
let result = {};
for (item of arr) {
    let parent = item.codeParent;
    if (parent !== '-') {
        let destArray = obj[parent];
        // if no array yet for this code, create one
        if (!destArray) {
           destArray = [];
           obj[parent] = destArray;
        }
        // add the new item to the destination array
        destArray.push(item);
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Some people will prefer to use `.reduce()` for this:

```
let result = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    let parent = item.codeParent;
    if (parent !== '-') {
        let destArray = obj[parent];
        // if no array yet for this code, create one
        if (!destArray) {
           destArray = [];
           obj[parent] = destArray;
        }
        // add the new item to the destination array
        destArray.push(item);
    }
    return obj;    
}, {});
```

Note, each loop has slightly more code because I'm trying to only have to look up `obj[item.codeParent]` once for each iteration rather than multiple times and also trying to only look up the `codeParent` propery in `item.codeParent` once too.  You could do it with less code like this and slightly less efficient:

```
let result = arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
    if (item.codeParent !== '-') {
        if (!obj[item.codeParent]) {
            obj[item.codeParent] = [];
        }
        obj[item.codeParent].push(item);
    }
    return obj;    
}, {});
```

Note that this looks up `obj[item.codeParent]` 2 or 3 times in every iteration whereas the previous two versions look it up 1 or 2 times.